# while getting a p element from DOM get the error Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript

I need to take the text of an element from my DOM and pass it to a function. but I get an error on the line below

```
const status =  document.getElementById("word").innerText
```

the error is : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')

I am certain that the element with "word" id is not null, I can't find what the problem is or where the null comes from

Comment: See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959) - either you'll find the answer there or you need to provide more information and a [mcve].

Comment: Can you share your html?